# Send push notification GCM by java

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have configured a client android Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) to receive push notifications, but I can not configure a server in java to send notifications to devices. How could I?

Comment: You need to configure a server somewhere in internet-land, such as using Google App Engine, to do the server-side work.

Comment: yes, I have a server that connects to devices using sockets, but I can not send notifications to the GCM server from another server.

Comment: If you have a server already, post the code that doesn't work, and we'll try to fix it for you. Your question is too broad - we need to see what you've tried to do first.

Comment: How to register my Android device using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). I search for whole day and didn't find anything. Please help  me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [gcm-server.jar](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/server/package-summary.html) which contains helper methods for GCM messaging.
To get this jar you can install ***"[Deprecated]Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library"*** through Android SDK Manager. Don't let the deprecated name confuse you. Only the client part is deprecated, not server side.
After install you can find it at `"ADT_SDKROOT\sdk\extras\google\gcm"`. The sample folder contains a demo server which is very easy to understand.
Sending a GCM message involves only few lines of code:

```
    final String GCM_API_KEY = "yourKey";
    final int retries = 3;
    final String notificationToken = "deviceNotificationToken";
    Sender sender = new Sender(GCM_API_KEY);
    Message msg = new Message.Builder().build();

    try {
                Result result = sender.send(msg, notificationToken, retries);

                if (StringUtils.isEmpty(result.getErrorCodeName())) {
                    logger.debug("GCM Notification is sent successfully");
                    return true;
                }

                logger.error("Error occurred while sending push notification :" + result.getErrorCodeName());
    } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
                logger.error("Invalid Request", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("IO Exception", e);
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: if it worked, you should consider accepting the answer. It'll be useful to others :)

Comment: Hi I tried this using Eclipse and got this error. Any idea how to solve this? `Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
at NotificationSenderClass.main(NotificationSenderClass.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)...`

Comment: I downloaded the gcm.server.jar file and added it as library. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where i have to pass my projectID ? GCMRegID of receiver device?

Answer (score 1):

For """test""" create java console app, add gcm jar file.

```
    try{
     Sender sender = new Sender("<senderId>");
     ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
     devicesList.add(<deviceId>);
     String data = "<data>";
     Message message = new Message.Builder()
                        .collapseKey("1")
                        .timeToLive(3)
                        .delayWhileIdle(true)
                        .addData("message",
                                data)
                        .build();
    MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
                sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);

                System.out.println(result.toString());
                if (result.getResults() != null) {
                    int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
                    if (canonicalRegId != 0) {
                    }
                } else {
                    int error = result.getFailure();
                    System.out.println(error);
                }

}
```