# Can we send push notification to APNs from iOS device?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to send push notification from a iOS device to another iOS device without using backend server. Is it possible for an iOS device to act like a server and send push notification to APNs server?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Theoretically you can send Apple Push Notifications from a device directly to another device. All you need are the push certificate of the app, the device token of the device you are sending the notification to, and code that establishes a secure TLS connection to the APNS servers.

However, there are several practical problems that make the use of a server almost mandatory :

1. You need a single place where all the device tokens of all the devices that installed your app will be sent to and persisted in. The best such place would be a server. Without a server, how would device A send its device token to other devices that want to send it push notifications?
2. Apple require that you keep connections with the APNS server open for as long as possible and use the same connection for sending many notifications. If you open a connection to APNS server on your device, it will probably be short lived (since devices switch networks frequently, and don't stay connected to the internet all the time). Therefore, if you try to send many notifications frequently, and each time use a new connection to APNS, you will probably be banned (since Apple would treat this as DDoS attack).
3. If you store the push certificate in each device that installs your app (to allow it to send push notifications to other devices directly), aside from the security issue of storing the certificate in many places, you'll have to publish a new version of your app each time the push certificate expires (once a year), and push notifications would stop working for users who don't upgrade to the new version.

Comment: Thanks for your concise explanation... @Eran

Answer (score 2):

Try [NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher).

It has an iOS framework for sending pushes and has an iOS demo application that sends push notifications from iOS to iOS.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to consider Server costs (other than maintenance and development time if you code your own server).

By sending the push directly from the app device:
- you obtain a much better scalability (since you don't have to centralize everything on your server)
- you don't have to pay for server cost or other service's cost

You can use for iOS:
- https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher Pusher

And for Android:
- [Send push notification GCM by java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853129/send-push-notification-gcm-by-java)

Comment: The purpose of NWPusher (which was already suggested in another answer), as stated by its creator, is **not** to replace the server. Its purpose is to test push notifications without going through the trouble of setting up a server. This is not a scalable solution, since it requires storing all the device tokens to which your app wants to send notifications. Copy and pasting a couple of device tokens for testing is one thing. Doing the same with thousands on device tokens is less practical. A real app in production requires a server.

Comment: That's not true, you can request the device token form your server when you need it, and then send the push from the device. You don't need to store all the token on your device , but even that you could do it, if you are an app messagning you have to store information about your contact anyway in your app.

Comment: Then you agree with me that a server is required. Your answer suggests otherwise.

Comment: You need a server for example if you have a database that you need to store information, i agree with you. But to effectively send the push you can simply do it in your app, no need to hop between another server, just contact apple or google server and send it. This is more scalable since you don't have to set up a worker queue to process the push and you don't have costs associated to your server for push.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. I have a server for hub access by my apps, but couldn't use push from the server due to not having port 2195 access. Now I can use the server to collect device tokens and send the push direct from the app to as many devices as I like. Thanks.