# Sending Apple Push Notification directly from device to device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

As far as I can read, it is technically possible to initiate an Apple Push Notification from an iOS App instead of via a server/service.

It would require the push notification certificate to be bundled with the app, and device tokens for the receiving devices must be exchanged.

Offhand this seems like a usable solution for some notification scenarios, but are there other limitations? Would such a setup not be accepted in an App submitted to the app store? Would exchanging device tokens pose some sort of risk? It would save the cost of a notification service and it would distribute the processing to the clients instead of the server.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427500/can-we-send-push-notification-to-apns-from-ios-device

Answer (score -1):

try NWPusher...
this is a third party but sends notification from ios to